# Storing configurations

Tags: database, oracle

I'm currently working on generalizing a platform, which handles incoming payments, potentially keeps some of it for offsetting reasons, and then payouts the rest. For now, the system has been made to work with a single type of incoming payment, but we're now generalizing it to handle different types. Each payment type has its own quirks, but a lot of similarities, so we have decided to extract all behavior that varies between each type of "money" in database tables. The tables basically store user configurations, such as algorithms (basically different code fragments, i.e., the name of code to be executed), booleans and passed parameters.

We must store the history of previously configured values for a particular type of money, since configurations may change over time. Eventually there is a finite number of configuration points in the code.

**Solutions**

It seems as though there basically exists 3 overall approaches for storing "user" configurations. Either as an EAV table in the RBDMS, make explicit columns for each configuration, or leverage JSON/XML/some other text format.

**EAV**

EAV has its obvious strengths in making everything very general, and thus easy to extract from the database. The largest concern is data integrity, and that every configuration parameter must be specified for every type of money, and ensuring that becomes more difficult in EAV. Keeping the history is straightforward: simply add a version/timestamp column, and select the latest version for a particular type of money.

**Explicit columns**

Explicit columns, i.e., one column for every configuration point, makes it much simpler to ensure that all configuration points have been defined. Since there eventually are no more additions of configuration points, it seems preferable to EAV. Keeping a history becomes more troublesome, though. Oracle comes with audit functionality, but does not seem to present itself easily to be presented in a GUI. A seperate log table can be leveraged, but is cumbersome to maintain, especially if this is done by using triggers. Every addition of a column (i.e., new configuration point) means that the trigger has to be regenerated.

An alternative to the trigger, is to have a versioning column in the configuration tables. Then, a view can be used on top of the configuration table, selecting the latest row for each type of money. However, adding a new column becomes troublesome, as if it's non-nullable, old rows (i.e. those that have become history), must be updated with potentially bogus values. This can obviously be avoided by relaxing the non-nullable constraint, but then data integrity becomes much worse, as the values *must* be specified.

I haven't looked too much into the JSON/XML approach, but it seems to have many of the same problems as EAV.

My question: is there a standardized way of approaching this? It seems that most people who deal with user configurations, don't have to keep an exact history in tables as well. One could simply use the migration SQL files that are created, but configurations may be changed from a GUI as well.

Comment: Not sure what you're thinking of when you discuss Oracle's *"audit functionality"* but its FLASHBACK DATA ARCHIVE capability is pretty simple to use and seems perfectly compatible with a  GUI. [Find out more ](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1)

Comment: Unfortunately the system is part of a distributed monolith, so a shared database is used. There is a rather short retention period in place for flashbacks queries (think days), when we need to permanently keep a history record.

Comment: Your assessment of the supposed strengths of EAV are wildly optimistic.  Far from making it 'easy' to extract data, it makes it orders of magnitude more difficult.  See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: Well, in this case, the configuration consumer always knows the type of money + which type of configuration is in question. Which forms the unique key to the particular configuration value that is needed. That's why EAV is not such a bad design in that regard.

Comment: Rather than use a trigger to maintain history, could you a `start_date` column which denotes the point at which the new value becomes live. Adjusting the queries to grab the relevant values at a given point in time should be not too difficult. History is automatically maintained this way by natural data entry, i.e. each time a new value is added, the START_DATE is also set.

As for the problem with historic data handling newly added NOT NULL, a sentinel value to denote 'N/A', worked into relevant queries would work..

Comment: FLASHBACK DATA ARCHIVE is not the same as Flashback Query. FDA employs journalling tables behind the scenes to maintain version history of data **for years**. Retrieval of a record at any given point in time is just a matter of using AS OF clause when we SELECT. It's way simpler than any of the options you posted here. Please read the article.

Comment: @TenG One caution to be aware of is performance. We have some databases from a vendor that use this method. Complex joins where we always want to use the current value can result in some horrific execution plans and terrible performance. Indexing is only moderately helpful.

Comment: @TenG isn't that solved pretty easily by having a view on top of the underlying table though?